# Mistake on using pointers-to-members in Clang

Tags: c++, clang++, pointer-to-member

The following code compiles gcc successfully

```
template<typename T>
class F {
public:
    template<typename V>
    static void foo(V T::*) {
        p<bool> = nullptr;
    }

    template<typename V>
    static inline V T::* p;
};

struct A;
template class F<A>;

int main() {
}
```

and clang compilation fails with

```
<source>:10:18: error: member pointer refers into non-class type 'bool'

        static inline V T::* p;

                        ^

<source>:6:3: note: in instantiation of static data member 'F::p' requested here

                p<bool> = nullptr;

                ^
```

https://godbolt.org/z/NX7VmH

is this invalid code or i don't understand clang?

Comment: Just curious. What exactly the notation ::* mean? And how p<bool> should work? What exactly is p?

Comment: @armagedescu https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_members

Comment: p::* is a pointer-to-member of T. For example, bool A::* p = &A::b

Comment: Ok. Then saying p<bool> you are trying to restrict the type to bool* or to some sort of ptr<bool>?

Comment: No, it`s only example. If you substitute T instead of bool: p<T> = nullptr;. It compiles successfully. But this is wrong.

Comment: Ok. Suppose it is p<bool>. Is it supposed to resolve as instance of bool* or as a instance of some sort of wrapper like shared_ptr<bool>? Keep in mind, if V is a class like shared_ptr then V T::*  requires a shared_ptr<>*, not just a shared_ptr<>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is valid from a pure language perspective. That is a valid variable template, and the resulting variable is itself of a valid type (a pointer to member). As a matter of fact, Clang complains even [without the explicit instantiation](https://godbolt.org/z/D5RNKb).

And to drive the point home, Clang has no problem with this variable template if you move the `p<bool>` expression [outside of the template](https://godbolt.org/z/_2MDUr). It's a bug in Clang that causes it to reject your code.

Comment: Note: please log this at bugs.llvm.org